# How to stop permission denied when moving a folder to a directory

Tags: bash

I'm trying to move a folder with mv to a directory I created, however I'm getting permission denied repeatedly....any advice would be great. I know I can use sudo, but want to know why I can't do it

Tried recreating a directory but no joy[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Mzr.png)

Comment: This looks like a bash question, not a java question. And it isn't really programming related. I recommend that you read about the permissions system for Linux to figure out what you need to do.

Comment: In Linux, you generally shouldn't create directories in the root `/` directory unless you know what you are doing. Usually you create directories in your personal directory at `/hom/username`. You can use the `~` shortcut to reference this home directory.

Comment: Do `ls -l /projects` and look at the permissions, the user and the group. Are you one of those who have permission to write to `/projects`? Does `/projects` even exist?

Answer (score 1):

First check if you have permission to access the /projects folder `ls -l projects/` if you have it, use `mv fileName projects/`, if not , try to change the folder owner using `chown yourUser:yourUser` and repeat the mv command.

Comment: What is `chown` going to do if OP doesn't have permissions?